# ZeroConf (Bonjour/Avahi): Macs do not see Linux systems and vice versa

Tags: ubuntu, mac-osx, bonjour, avahi

In my home network I have several OS X boxes and several Ubuntu boxes.

Each Ubuntu box sees other boxes via ZeroConf.

I can "ssh ubuntu1.local" and "ping ubuntu1.local" from "ubuntu2.local", but both fail to lookup OSX boxes.

And the other way around, I can "ssh mini1.local" from "mbair.local", but it doesn't see "ubuntu1.local".

Why? Do Ubuntu and OS X use different flavours of ZeroConf? Could Ubuntu, or OS X be tweaked to use a common flavour?

Comment: Can you ping or ssh from linux to OSX or the otherway around by their IP addres? They need to be on the same subnet for default installs of bonjour/zeroconf/ etc to work.